# Print two ArrayLists side by side when one ArrayList is for Strings

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, printing

I have two `ArrayList`s of the same size but one of the `ArrayList`s holds strings.

For example:

```
List 1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List 2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

(apple , orange , pear , banana , kiwi) are in list 1
(5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1) are in list 2

I want it to print like this:

```
apple 5
orange 4
pear 3
banana 2
kiwi 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming they're the same size, you can iterate over them together:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.println(list1.get(i) + " " + list2.get(i));
}
```